# Android OkHTTP Multipart - body is empty server side

Tags: android, node.js, okhttp

I'm attempting to send multipart data, (`image & JSON`) to my server,
however when I try using `okHttp` multipart body, the request body on the server is always empty where in this case i would be expecting
 `{fieldname: "some field name" }`

Super stuck on this so any help would be greatly appreciated. I can do a normal body with RequestBody and that works fine, and a multipart body with just an image, its just the dual JSON and image in a multipart doesnt seem to be sending through the json body.

NOTE: I have tried this without including the image/file as a form data part to see if the field_name would now show in the req body server side but that has not worked either.

```
    RequestBody multiPartForm = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("field_name", "some field name")
            .addFormDataPart("image", "somefile.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, new File(getPath(uri))))
            .build();


    String apiRoute = apiURL + '/' + route;
    Request.Builder reqBuilder = new Request.Builder();

    reqBuilder.header("x-access-token", APIToken);

    Request.Builder builder = reqBuilder.url(apiRoute);
    builder.post(multiPartForm);

    return client.newCall(builder.build());
```

Comment: `.addFormDataPart("image", "somefile.jpg", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, new File(getPath(uri))))` here your file may be `null`

Comment: Hey, sorry to clarify, the image/file part is not entirely relevant because although I will be needing to include it along with JSON data part, at this point i am focusing on the JSON body in req (in this case "field_name"). But to also answer your question the file in this case is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setType(MultipartBody.FORM)` and see if that works.

Comment: did not seem to make a difference unfortunately